# div ID navigation/scrollTo not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, scrollto

My div links aren't working in chrome but works fine in safari and firefox. On click an audio effect autoplays and the div should move horizontally. In chrome, the audio starts but the navigation doesn't move.

I've looked through similar issues on here and tried implementing their fixes but no go: nothing changed when I tried updating the jquery library and scrollTo. Not sure what the root problem is so would appreciate a fresh pair of eyes on this!

On github: https://github.com/damarisdus/evening-star

Live site: http://web.pdx.edu/~ddusciuc/342/evening_star/index.html

```
<nav class="back">
    <a link="#page1" class="page1_link"><img src="img/nav/back.png"></a>
</nav>

<nav>
    <a link="#page3" class="page3_link"><img src="img/nav/fig_2.png"></a>
</nav>
```

---

```
$("nav a").click(function(){
    var page_id = $ (this).attr("link");
    $(window).scrollTo($(page_id), 4000);  
});

$("#page2").waypoint(function(direction) {
    if(direction == 'right') {
        $("nav a").removeClass("selected");
        $(".page2_link").addClass("selected");
        $(".fadeIn").fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else {
        $("nav a").removeClass("selected");
        $(".page1_link").addClass("selected");
        $(".fadeIn").fadeOut(1000);
    }

},{ 
    horizontal: true
});

    $("#page3").waypoint(function(direction) {
    if(direction == 'right') {
        $("nav a").removeClass("selected");
        $(".page3_link").addClass("selected");
        $(".fadeIn").fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else {
        $("nav a").removeClass("selected");
        $(".page2_link").addClass("selected");
        $(".fadeIn").fadeOut(1000);
    }

},{ 
    horizontal: true
});
```